# How to change partitions so Filesystem root has enough space

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, gparted

I am getting warnings that my Filesystem root is running out of space. I have tried a number of things which the internet told me to do, but nothing seems to be solving the problem.

I am running Ubuntu MATE 20.04 with a hard disk (sda) and an SSD (sdb); gparted shows this:

[image: gparted image of sda]
[image: gparted image of sdb]

I have very little experience with partitions and such, but it seems to me that if sdb5 could be extended to include what is now sdb6, that would double the space available to the root of mate 20.04.

But, I would like to preserve mate 16.04 if possible.  Looking at sda, there is a partition sda9 (called "huge unused") which has way more than enough space for mate 16.04.  So my detailed plan is this:

Move the mate 16.04 partition from SSD to hard drive:
Split sda9 (currently 385.51 GiB)) into two partitions of these sizes:
sda9    355.51 GiB
sda10    30.00 GiB
Copy sdb6 (mate 16.04) to sda10.
Change boot options so that 16.04 can still be launched from
its new location.

Increase the space available to mate 20 on the SSD:
Combine the three partitions sdb5, unallocated, and sdb6 into
one partition.

Will this work?  And, if so, what I desperately need are detailed instructions on how to execute the plan.  My experience with gparted is quite limited.

A secondary question is why mate 20.04 is using 28 GiB while mate 16.04 is using only 14 GiB.

A friend of mine, Mike, set up all the partitions on my system, and normally I would go to him for help.  But a few months ago he left the planet, so I am more or less on my own in terms of keeping my system going.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but because your root file system is on `sdb5` and you don't have any unallocated space after that, you cannot extend the partition unless you remove the partition immediately following, which is where you have 16.04.  Anyway, Ubuntu MATE 16.04 has been EOL for well over two years. It's no longer acceptable to use this operating system, so copy what you need from it and remove it. Then you can extend your partition to the adjacent space.

Comment: 30 GB should be sufficient for a / partition, provided you manage it - do not store too much old kernels, keep the size of your logs under control, make sure nothing is there that does not belong there, move temp folders to a different partition... Many snaps or flatpaks nowadays require much more space though than APT applications.